# Conditions on a bivariate distribution to be the distribution of $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)$, $(X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)$ and $(X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a bivariate probability distribution $P: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,1]$. I have the following questions:

Are there ***necessary and sufficient*** conditions **on the cumulative distribution function (CDF)  associated with $P$** (joint or marginal) ensuring that
$$
\exists \text{ a random vector $(X_0,X_1,X_2)$ such that }
$$
$$
(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2), (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1), (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)
$$
 $$
\text{ have all probability distribution $P$? }
$$

---

Notice:

$(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$ **does not imply** that some of the random variables among $X_1, X_2, X_0$ are degenerate. For example, $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$ **is implied by** $(X_0, X_1, X_2)$ **exchangeable.**

---

**My thoughts:** among the **necessary** conditions, I would list the following: let $G$ be the CDF associated with $P$ and let $G_1,G_2$ be the two marginal CDFs. Then it should be that
$$
\begin{cases}
G_1 \text{ is symmetric around zero, i.e., $G_1(a)=1-G_1(-a)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$}\\
G_2 \text{ is symmetric around zero, i.e., $G_2(a)=1-G_2(-a)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Are these conditions also sufficient? If not, what else should be added to get an exhaustive set of sufficient and necessary conditions?

Comment: dont you mean "there exists a random vector $(X_0, X_1, X_2)$..."?  otherwise what is $X_0$?

Comment: the requirement is also not what i expected, because it doesnt have cyclic symmetry.  are you sure?

Comment: @antkam (1) Yes, edited. (2) What did you expect instead? What do you mean by "cyclic symmetry"? Is your "cyclic symmetry" an implication of exchangeability?

Comment: i mean if you cyclically substitute $X_0 \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow X_0$ then you would generate the similarity requirements like this: $(X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)\sim (X_1- X_2, X_1-X_0)$.  note the difference in the 3rd term.  however, you can of course require your version.  i am not sure it made much difference to be honest.  :)

Comment: I see. You are just flipping the components of my first argument. I think also your relation is an implication of exchangeability. I don't know if considering your relation rather than mine can make things easier, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a vector of random variables, or equivalently a random variable taking values in $\mathbb R^2$, we can write it as $(U,V)$ where $U$ is the $x$-coordinate and $V$ is the $y$-coordinate of the random vector. So
$$G_1(u)=\mathbb P(U\le u),$$
$$G_2(v)=\mathbb P(V\le v).$$

Now, in general if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X\le x)$, $F_Y(y)=\mathbb P(Y\le y)$, then we write $X\sim Y$ if $F_X=F_Y$.

---

Besides the conditions you give,

namely: if $(U,V)$ is a random variable on $R^2$ as desired then $U\sim -U$ and $V\sim -V$, where $\sim$ denotes "has the same distribution as",

there's also

> $$V-U\sim (X_0-X_2)-(X_0-X_1)= X_1-X_2\sim V$$

And note that $V\sim -V$, $U\sim -U$ does not imply $V-U\sim V$, e.g., take $U$, $V$ to be independent standard normal $N(0,1)$ random variables:
$$\mathrm{Var}(V-U)=\mathrm{Var}+\mathrm{Var}(U) = 2>1=\mathrm{Var}(V)$$

Comment: Thanks: 2 questions on that (1) How do I show that your condition is necessary? (2) Is your condition implying that one variable between $X_1, X_2$ should be  zero almost surely?

Comment: Regarding (1), I'm stuck here: $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\begin{cases}(X_1-X_2)\sim( X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_2)\\ (X_1-X_0)\sim (X_2-X_0) \sim (X_0-X_1) \end{cases}$ $\Rightarrow$ ...?

Comment: Regarding (2), I don't think that $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$ should imply that one variable between $X_1, X_2$ should be zero almost surely. Indeed, if $(X_0, X_1, X_2)$ exchangeable then $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$.

Comment: @STF I agree with you regarding (2). $V-U\sim V$ doesn't imply $U=0$. And regarding (1), the rule I use is that if $(U,V)\sim (X,Y)$ then $U\sim X$ and $V\sim Y$.

Comment: Thanks. (2) Can you make a parametric example of $V-U\sim V$?

Comment: Regarding (1) I'm still confused: (A) We have $X_1-X_2=(X_1-X_0)-(X_2-X_0)$ (B) We have that $(X_1-X_0)\sim (X_2-X_0)$ (C) We have that $X_2-X_1\sim X_1-X_2$. How should I link (A), (B),(C) to get your condition?

Comment: Thanks. Forget about "parametric". I would like an example of distribution satisfying $V-U\sim V$. Also, in my question I ask about necessary and **sufficient** conditions. I understand that the sufficiency part is tricky. Do you have some ideas on that?

Comment: @STF The example is the one you gave... $V=X_0-X_2$, $U=X_0-X_1$, where $X_i$ are exchangeable.

Comment: For sufficient condition, I guess you keep looking for more necessary conditions, and examples showing those are not sufficient, until you get stuck or you're done...

Comment: Thanks. that sounds hard, nothing more efficient than keep looking for more necessary conditions?